# How to efficiently download multiple files from SharePoint using R

Tags: r, sharepoint, httr, two-factor-authentication

I have an Excel file containing a list of 10,000+ documents (PDFs and Word document)  that I aim to download. Each file is linked to a SharePoint URL.

My goal is to devise a script in R that can automatically access and download these documents.

I tried the following, but it resulted in damaged downloads.

```
library(readxl)
library(httr) 

data <- read_excel("data/in/doclist.xlsx")
urls <- data$url

for (url in urls) {
  # Send a GET request to the URL
  response <- GET(url)
  
  # Extract the file name from the URL
  file_name <- basename(url)
  
  # Specify the path where you want to save the downloaded files
  save_path <- paste0("data/out/", file_name)
  
  # Save the downloaded file
  writeBin(content(response), save_path)
  
  # Print a message to indicate the successful download
  cat("File", file_name, "downloaded successfully.\n")
}
```

I cannot open the downloaded documents ("Word experienced an error trying to open the file" and "Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open xyz because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged").

I suspect the issue may be due to the two-factor authentication requirement to access these documents on SharePoint. When attempting to download publicly accessible PDFs, the code works smoothly, allowing me to open the downloaded files. Additionally, I can access the documents individually in SharePoint since I possess the necessary login credentials.

Any guidance or alternative approaches to do this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried `content(response, as="raw")`? I can't imagine it would do the wrong thing with a correct `Content-Type:` from the server, but perhaps it'll help. Otherwise, are you certain that the files on sharepoint are not themselves corrupted before download?

Comment: Unfortunately, that still doesn't work (i.e., the downloaded files are still broken). I tried opening the files one by one with an internet browser and they do not seem to be corrupted.

Comment: I would expect sharepoint to require authentication, but I don't see it in your call to `GET`. Have you checked `status_code(response)` to make sure it's in the 200s (not 401 or similar)? Are the files' sizes about right? Yes, if they're corrupted, they'll likely be some bytes off, but large files still large and small files still small? You can also check `length(content(response, as="raw"))` to see how many bytes the downloaded file is, and compare with what you expect.

Comment: I tried `response <- GET(url, authenticate("username", "password"))`, but I still end up with a bunch of damaged downloads. When checking  `status_code(response)`, I get 403, which seems aligned with what I thought regarding SharePoint access issue. The file sizes don't seem right as they are too small (1 KB each).

Comment: [HTTP `403`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) means "Forbidden" (all 400s mean something is wrong with the attempt). I don't know how to do it right, but one of: (1) your username/password do not match; (2) the document(s) has not been shared with your username; or (3) that authentication mechanism in general does not work for SharePoint.

Comment: I know nothing about it, but the [`Microsoft365R`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Microsoft365R/) package claims to support uploading/downloading shared files.

Comment: Side point: when I'm looking for how to do something in R and using google, I tend to include `"cran"` (quoted) in the search, as that will include the CRAN repository of packages their descriptions. (If using BioConductor, I think `"bioc"` is good too, but I don't work with those packages often enough to need it.) In that case, [`"cran" "sharepoint"`](https://www.google.com/search?q="cran"+"sharepoint") points directly to `Microsoft365R`, its vignettes (including *[Authentication](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Microsoft365R/vignettes/auth.html)*), its github repo, and some others.